# How to compute Rth for this circuit using OrCAD PSpice

Tags: thevenin, pspice, orcad

Take a look at this circuit
[image]

The question asks to find Rth and Vth between a-b terminals. Hand calculation yields Rth=3.857 and Vth=4V. With OrCAD, the result is shown below using Bias Point simulation:

[image]

Unequivocally, Vth=19-15=4V which agrees with the hand calculation. The problem is with computing Rth which is computed by changing the simulation to DC Sweep and find the slope between I2 and its voltage. If I do so, OrCAD starts from 19V rather than 4V but subtracting it by 15 to correct it which yields the following

[image]

Rth is the slope of the green line so, Rth=(6.429-4)/1=2.429. There is a big large error. Any suggestions.

Comment: Rth={3+2+5}//4 +1

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 this is hand calculation not Pspice. I've already solved it by hand.

Comment: For spice you can add R across “a,b” that is larger  change in V/I=Rth in nodes ab Using delta V/delta I to compute voltage drop from voltage divider and get exact Req.